# Deploying Aurelia app to Heroku Cannot GET /app/

Tags: node.js, heroku, aurelia

I am trying to deploy and run an [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/get-started.html) app on [heroku](https://www.heroku.com)

I forked this [using Aurelia with a NodeJS Express App](https://github.com/zewa666/aurelia-node) and followed the bouncing ball in the documentation [Getting Started with Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-the-app)

which was essentially

```
heroku create

git push heroku master
```

After some futzing around I worked out that on heroku needed all the development dependencies to the dependencies section of package.json.

Anyway, everything compiles and deploys now.

The problem is that I think heroku is intercepting the aurelia navigation so when I try and navigate to https://the-app-1234.herokuapp.com/app/ it reports that it

> Cannot GET /app/

How do I get it to behave properly?

EDIT:

I'm pretty sure this is not related to node.js because the application works just fine in my localhost. This is something to do with heroku.

Comment: I haven't used heroku. You're going to want to configure your node app to route /app/ to your aurelia app's index.html. The gulp task provided with the skeleton includes this step, but if you're doing it on a node based server you'll want to have your server do this instead of using the gulp task (which is for development).

Comment: I tried deploying the skeleton app to Heroku and wasn't able to get it working either, I ended up deploying to Azure as it didn't take any special setup (apart from a webconfig file to redirect to index.html as I'm using pushstate)